# How can I optimize the speed of reading files from an external HD in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, opencv

I need to process about 200 folders containing 300 pictures (205 kb) from an external HD.

I have the following loop within a thread.

```
ffs=FileFrameStream(lFramePaths).start()

#___While Loop through the frames____

image,path = ffs.read()

while ffs.more(): #While there is frames in the Queue to read
        try:
            img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
            #some more operations....
        except:
            print(f"Erorr in picture:{path}")
            image,path=ffs.read()
            count+=1
            continue
     image,path=ffs.read()
     count+=1
ffs.stop()
```

The code runs fast for 1 to 30-40 folders. One folder takes around 0.5s, and for 20 13.20s, but if I want to analyse the 200 folders, it takes 500-600 s. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong or how I can increase the performance of the code.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Eduardo

Comment: use a profiler to figure out _what_ takes time here. or take a stop watch and time your program's execution time. drop opencv stuff and see how long that took (difference).

Comment: Hi Christoph, Yeah, I used a line profiler to optimise the code. Each folder was taking 5s at the beginning. After that, I reduced it to 0.5s. It should take around 100 s to analyse the 200 folders, but it takes five times.

Comment: you missed the point of my question. the question isn't about how long the processing takes in total, it's about **what part of the code** takes how long, in relation to the other parts of the code. you didn't use a profiler yet.

Comment: 91.1% Time is in the line while ffs.more():  ffs.more() returns True if there is still frames in the queue. So it should be waiting for more frames to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably seeing effects of your operating-system's file cache. When parsing 200 files, it may go out of capacity and the actual streaming is done directly from disk instead of RAM.

Check if your OS file cache capacity is less than sum of 200 files' sizes or if it can cache the external drive or not. When data is beginning to not fit the cache, the performance drops exponentially, unless the disk drive is nearly as fast as RAM (I guess its not).

Comment: The total files (60,000) will be approx 12.3 mb  my hardware is:  Processor: Intel Core i7
  Processorspeed: 2.8 GHz
  Processors: 1
  Cores: 2
  L2-Cache (pro Core): 256 KB
  L3-Cache: 4 MB
  RAM: 16 GB

Comment: 60000 files for 12.3MB means 205 byte per file. Is this causing 2-3 seconds per 205 byte content? Then certainly it must be computational time (is it doing work in parallel, 1 thread per work?) as 100 bytes per second is nowhere any limit on a computer. I see only a while loop so it is serial work so no threads.

Comment: sorry it was 12,300 MB

Comment: The thread only does the cv2.imread() operation, because is really slow

Comment: If using windows 10, check registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SoftGrid\4.5\Client\AppFS\FileSize if using ubuntu "free" command shows current file cache usage. (use when running the app)

Comment: I'm using Mac OS High Sierra